# What is meant by auspicious in astrology?

Tags: astrology

What does it exactly meant by auspicious in astrology?

I am thinking that if someone feel liKe something happened good to themselves then its auspicious.

In that case consider the below scenario.

I wanted to go outside for some work then I realized that my vehicle has some problem.

Feeling sad that my vehicle has problem and I need to walk is inauspicios.

Feeling happy that I got a chance to walk as I was not doing physical activities from last few days is auspicious.

If something auspicious or inauspicious is decided by ones feelings then that person can make anything auspicious or inauspicious in his feelings only, then how astrology decides something auspicious or not? Astrology will become wrong right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Astrology is a highly ambiguous topic.
I will try to answer this using Taraka & not by Shastra, so kindly be considerate.

```
What does it exactly meant by auspicious in astrology?
```

Auspicious is when something you planned or were trying to accomplish goes as per your wish or the person is highly benefitted from the task. Thus, ultimately giving a sense of happiness, satisfaction and peace from within.

`In that case consider the below scenario.`

The scenario you described is very well put. First, let's understand this example,(purely hypothetical)

You have a very important job interview. That day your vehicle broke.(May the grace of Amba be upon you, & never let that happen.) So, next is you went to the bus stop & missed the bus. You trynna book a cab or whatever, but it shows it's far enough.
Now, this is what really inauspicious is. Under such circumstances, I know noone will think, maybe the job was by some scamster company, so I must be happy & go back home. Now the only option would be walk out that distance, you did & suppose u reached. So, will be in the mood for interview or presentation? U already will be highly frustrated & exhausted.

So, you see how the mentality changes, altough the same incidents of a vehicle breakdown, yet different moods.
Now, coming to what you said, if you walked all the way to workplace, and got happy since you had a workout, but suppose your workplace was 12kms & u walked that distance (hypothetically), even if u feel happy due to former, but would be sad too, for having walked so much. The highlighting point is you choose to see optimistic point. But, deep down a tinch of sadness too appears.

Being optimistic is one part. Refer the next part.

```
If something auspicious or inauspicious is decided by ones feelings then that person can make anything auspicious or inauspicious in his feelings only, then how astrology decides something auspicious or not?
```

The best example to clear whole doubt is here,

Valmiki Ramayana Yuddha Kanda 6.65.50,     mentions bad omen signalling Kumbhakarna,

> निष्पपात च गृध्रेऽस्य शूले वै पथि गच्छतः |
> प्रास्फुरन्नयनम् चास्य सव्यो बाहुरकम्पत ||
> A vulture descended on the spike of Kumbhakarna, as he was sallying forth along the road. His left eye twitched and his left arm throbbed.

If you know Kumbhakaran was very happy that, he will die at the hands of Śrī Rām and thus get moksha. But, you see inauspicious signs appeared to him, since his death approached.
Thus, seeing his chance of being liberated was his optimism, but the reality was it was his death.
So, one can fool himself by thinking positivity but, not the effect. If one say, how can death be inauspicious if he was killed by Rām himself, that's the death everyone wants.
Now let's truly understand this, in next part.

```
Astrology will become wrong right?
```

Astrology can be get ridden only after, a person is truly realized, only then he finds no pain or pleasure. Then he has no auspicious or inauspicious happenings. Till the time you are attached to the body, the Mind & ego (buddhi & ahamkara) will play around. And these two, get's affected by astrology. Atma has no mangalamangala.
But, identity with body does.
Likewise, Kumbhakaran was attached to his body, thus he said to Ravana that with his whole body he can crush half of the army. Thus, the statement that he will get moksha (trying to show as if he is realized soul) was just staged up to sooth himself.
A person can fool himself, but not the nature.
I remembered a short folk anecdote, will cite here.
A person killed a cow, who was grazing in his fields. When, Gauhatya (sin for killing cow) approached him he said smartly, hands killed her and it was not him. And since the, hands r ruled by Indra, the hatya must go to him. To cut short, the gauhatya went to Indra, Indra said, I'm ruled by Vishnu, the lords of all. Thus hatya went upon Vishnu. The lord got in a fix.
He took a cow to that person's farm & became a brahmins boy himself. When the cow started eating his crops, the farmer who killed prior cow came running, and started pulling the cow outside. Vishnu as Brahmin asked him why was he taking cow out. The Brahmin instantly said, the farm is mine and the cow is destroying my crops. The lord said, if he sowed the seeds? The man noded and said, indeed it was him. Vishnu immediately called upon Gauhatya and said to go with the man. Because, he just staged up the knowledge to get free of sin. But, for merits he said, "it was me."

So, the moral is however happiness one tries to find or **act** as realized soul, but the Prakriti knows the truth and acts accordingly.

**कालिकार्पणमास्तु ।**